Identifiable Entity: UUID() vs UUID().uuidString
I used to define an identifiable entity this way:
struct Person: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    /* ... */
}

Recently I have seen this variation:
struct Person: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    /* ... */
}

Basically they both work. But which one is preferable and why?

If you can use the object itself go ahead. Its string purpose it is only to make it possible to represent it as human readable. The only drawback of using a string is that you might need to convert it from string to UUID back and forth

@LeoDabus Thanks LeoDabus. That makes it clear. If you like: Turn your comment into an answer. I will accept it.

Be aware that using the uuidstring will use 36 bytes instead of 16 bytes (uuid raw bytes)

@LeoDabus It's even worse than that. Those 36 bytes are for characters alone, but it actually takes more like 88 bytes in total. 8 bytes for the String struct itself, which points to a heap allocate storage object. That object has a 32 byte header, the 36 bytes of characters, then another 12 unused bytes of "slack" (malloc_size returns 80). Worse yet, it incurs arc retain/release overhead whenever it's copied, unlike the `UUID which just copies the 16 bytes directly, with no heap allocation to worry about

@Alexander Yes at least 36 bytes
